# How to use category type and treegrid type together in highcharts gantt?

Tags: highcharts

I want to have a Gantt chart like the below picture with highcharts. is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information, like what should happen with this custom category when the tree grid will be toggled?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Actually I want to category the tree grids in my Gantt chart. if the tree grids are toggled, the related category will be stretched.

Comment: I am afraid that with the current implementation it is impossible to achieve it from regular API options - a lot of custom changes needs to be done to create it. In the current implementation using the `grid` feature requires defined the y value in the data which is inconsistent with the `tree grid` feature. You can report this idea on Highcharts Github issue channel - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I've found it as a impossible thing to do, but I wanted to share my question to understand that is there someone who can help me or not!

Comment: sure thing, but I tried to implement it and I must resign for this idea because it requires much more work/time than is predicted for regular support - in those cases, we suggest to report the idea about the new functionality to core developers or on Highcharts userVoice channel https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api If this feature will get enough votes will be implemented. If you want to do it by yourself for your particular requirements here is my idea/attempt how to start: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ckumL6vo/

Comment: API to used featutres: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: @SebastianWędzel That's it. thank you so much.